# friend classes with pointers to each other

Tags: c++, class, friend

How can I create two classes that have member pointers to each other's class type, with full access to each other's data? In other words, I need two classes like this:

```
class A
{
protected:
   B *p;
};

class B
{
protected:
   A *p;
};
```

I'm having trouble with it because I'm not up to par with C++ conventions, and obviously, class A can't declare a class B because B is declared later in the code.

Thanks for the help

Comment: c++ is a place where friends have access to your private members. Had to mention it here :P

Comment: Of course the question is: if you have two classes that are so heavily coupled together then are you sure your design is correct? Certainly sounds like you have a class boundary wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use forward class declaration.

```
//in A.h

    class B; // forward declaration
    class A
    {
    protected:
       B *p;
       friend class B; // forward declaration
    };

//in B.h
class A; // forward declaration
class B
{
protected:
   A *p;
   friend class A; // forward declaration
};
```

Comment: will it work if we remove the line "friend class A;" - so that B can not access "private member of A" back? is that line optional? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class B;
class A {
    friend class B;
  protected:
    B *p;
};

class B {
    friend class A;
  protected:
    A *p;
};
```

Note that any member functions of A which actually use the members of B will have to be defined after the definition of B, for example:

```
class B;
class A {
    friend class B;
  protected:
    B *p;
    A *getBA();
};

class B {
    friend class A;
  protected:
    A *p;
};

A *A::getBA() { return p->p; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use forward declaration like:

```
class B;
class A{
   ...
   friend class B;
};
```

Comment: Thanks... What about the friendship?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
protected:
   class B *p;
};
```

If you want to declare friendship, you need a forward declaration:

```
class B;

class A
{
friend class B;
protected:
   B *p;
};
```

Comment: Not worth a downvote IMO, but you don't actually *need* a separate forward declaration in your second example. You could do `friend class B` and also `class B *p`, and leave out the first `class B;`.

Comment: @Steve Yes, you are right. Don't know what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B;
class A
{
protected:
   B *p;
   friend class B;
};

class B
{
protected:
   A *p;
   friend class A;
};
```

Comment: Will this code allow class A to use inline functions that were declared in class B?

Comment: @old-school rules: `inline` is completely unrelated to whether functions are accessible or not.

Comment: @Old-school rules: Yes, of course. Inline has nothing to do with friendship

Answer (score 1):

You could use a forward declaration by doing `class B;` above class A

Answer (score 1):

simple use:
    class B;

```
class A
{
    protected:
       B *p;
       friend class B;
};

class B
{
    protected:
       A *p;
       friend class A;
};
```

Using class B; means a forward declaration and this basically tells the compiler: "class B exists somewhere".